# How to create a dialog like CameraCaptureUI.CaptureFileAsync?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to create a library behaving like the [CaptureFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.capturefileasync.aspx) method, i.e. on a method call it would open up a full screen page with standard back navigation and return result to the caller.

I want to be able to call it the same way CaptureFileAsync is called:

```
var dialog = new Library.Dialog();
var result = await dialog.Show();
```

In the `Show` method I'm currently navigating to my own page and returning a `Task` which can be awaited by the caller:

```
public Task<string> Show()
{
    var task = new Task<string>(() => result);

    var frame = ((Window.Current.Content) as Frame);
    frame.Navigate(typeof(DialogPage));

    return task;
}
```

I call `task.Start()` when the dialog is being closed (either cancelled by navigating back or confirmed by pressing a button) which causes the result to be returned to the awaiting caller.

The problem is that when `Frame.GoBack()` is called, a new instance of the previous page is created and the result gets returned to the old instance which is not displayed any more. This is not how `CaptureFileAsync` works: in its case the same instance of the calling page is kept.

My question is: how can I display a page from my library without affecting the frame navigation and inadvertently causing a new instance of the calling page to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your UI on a Popup.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I was just thinking about it on my way to work today. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PopupHelper](http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/turn-any-usercontrol-into-a-pleasing-dialogflyout-in-windows-8/).

It abstracts all the ickines of using Popups and takes care of animation, disabling access to controls etc.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly an answer to my original question, but it looks like a nice wrapper to make working with popups easier. Have you considered making a library out of it and putting it on NuGet?

Comment: No - but I have no issue helping somebody do it if they want. Why do you say it won't help your original question? You want a "page" to navigate to that will not cause your previous page to lose context. That's exactly what this does (and the Popup answer above was marked as "answer" - this just makes it easier)

Comment: You're right, it might not be a direct answer, but it does help making it work :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this is what I came up with:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" 
      Background="#7F000000">
    <Grid Width="480" Height="180" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Custom Capture!" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="20"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**The Control**

```
public sealed partial class CustomCaptureControl : UserControl
{
    private StorageFile file;
    private ManualResetEvent reset;
    private Popup _mainPopup;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public CustomCaptureControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Rect windowBounds = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Bounds;
        this.MainGrid.Width = windowBounds.Width;
        this.MainGrid.Height = windowBounds.Height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<StorageFile> ShowAsync()
    {
        StorageFile file = await Task.Run(() => this.GetFile());
        return file;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<StorageFile> GetFile()
    {
        //Launch Popup in UI thread
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
        {
            this._mainPopup = new Popup();
            this._mainPopup.Child = this;
            this._mainPopup.IsOpen = true;
        });

        //Await user input
        await Task.Run(() => this.AwaitUserInput());

        return this.file;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task AwaitUserInput()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { this.reset });
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri fileURI = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SomeFile.pdf");
        this.file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileURI);

        this.reset.Set();

        this._mainPopup.IsOpen = false;
        this._mainPopup = null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
CustomCaptureControl capture = new CustomCaptureControl();
StorageFile file = await capture.ShowAsync();
```